# Href route with parameter in Laravel Php

Tags: php, laravel

I know this is common to ask, but I have the trouble of the correct way of routing my URL using `href`

**I've tried this**

```
<a href="{{ route('staff.emvvalidationdetails.emvcard',emv.evd_id)}}">
```

**but it returns me an error**

```
Use of undefined constant emv - assumed 'emv' (this will throw an Error in a future version of PHP)
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('emvvalidationdetailsemvcard', 'EmvvalidationdetailsController@emvcard')->name('staff.emvvalidationdetails.emvcard');
```

**Controller**

```
public function emvcard(Request $request, GetEmvDetailsByEvdId $getEmvDetailsByEvdId)
{

    $records = $getEmvDetailsByEvdId->execute($request->evd_id);
    // return response()->json($records);
    $breadcrumbs_main = 'Validated Accounts';
    $bradcrumbs_details = '-';
    return view('staff.emvvalidationdetails.update_card',['data_object' => $records],compact('breadcrumbs_main', 'breadcrumbs_details'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see here [Laravel route](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/helpers#method-route) that the `route()` function accepts 3 parameters, the second parameter you are providing is neither a string nor php-variable so that is why PHP assuming that you might have provided a PHP Constant as a parameter in second argument.

If you have a variable named `$emv`, then you can do something like this:

> If $emv is an object: `route('staff.emvvalidationdetails.emvcard',$emv->evd_id)`

> if $emv is an array: `route('staff.emvvalidationdetails.emvcard',$emv['evd_id'])`

Make sure you provide appropriate parameters.

Comment: `<div class="custom"  v-for="(emv, index) in emvdetailsdata" :key="emv.evd_id"  >` the `emv` is my loop variable like that